# Timers and performance for mobile JS

Tags: javascript, mobile, webgl, three.js, timing

I'm using the Three.js JavaScript library to do some things in WebGL, and **I wonder how the graphic aspects of timers are done on mobile.**

I was creating numbers with geometries and just replacing them when needed. This was fine on desktop (or so I think, lol). Recently, I've been playing around with mobile and the previous method is far too slow.

Comment: You really need to explain better what you're trying to do, and what "I was creating numbers with geometries and just replacing them when needed" means. Or we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Graphics timing in modern browsers, including (especially) on mobile, is done via `requestAnimationFrame()`, introduced as a result of the W3C's specs on [timing control for script-based animations](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/RequestAnimationFrame/Overview.html), replacing the older `setInterval()` approach. Both call an event handler.

`requestAnimationFrame()` (RAF) ensures far more reliable / regular timing than `setInterval()` and the like. How it works (loosely) under the hood is to let the browser know that what is currently happening in the timed event handler is an animation, and as such certain measures should be taken (by supporting browsers) to ensure this process proceeds smoothly. And to quote MSDN:

> simplifies animations by  scheduling the next animation frame only when the system is ready to
>   paint. This leads to smoother animations and less power consumption
>   than previous animation techniques because requestAnimationFrame takes
>   the visibility of the web application and the refresh rate of the
>   display into account.

At least for Mozilla-based browsers and IE, RAF will typically match the display refresh rate and so generally guarantees a steady refresh period / frequency of around 60FPS, although admittedly Opera [docs](https://dev.opera.com/articles/better-performance-with-requestanimationframe/) suggest that RAF does *not* guarantee this. In general, however, I would go with the Chrome/Firefox/IE recommendation, which is that you can rely on the rate noted above.

Under the hood, Three.js will be using RAF, or if the browser doesn't support it, will fall back to `setInterval()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So to clear things up I understand how RAF works. I'm just trying to find a light weight way to draw the timer. To answer your question about "I was creating numbers with geometries and just replacing them when needed". Three.js has an easy way to turn text or numbers into 3D objects. So my timer would start at 45 and every second I would just replace the current object with the next value needed. This was to slow. So on mobile what is the preferred method for drawing numbers of a particular font.

Comment: Ok so I just realized the confusion. When I say counter I mean clock. Like how street fighter has a timer that counts down to Zero. Sorry